# C++ class member function callback

Tags: c++, class, function, callback, member

I have the following problem. I have a function from an external library (which cannot be modified) like this:

```
void externalFunction(int n, void udf(double*) );
```

I would like to pass as the udf function above a function member of an existing class. Please look at the following code:

```
// External function (tipically from an external library)
void externalFunction(int n, void udf(double*) )
{
     // do something
}

// User Defined Function (UDF)
void myUDF(double* a)
{
      // do something
}

// Class containing the User Defined Function (UDF)
class myClass
{
public:
    void classUDF(double* a)
    {
        // do something...
    };
};

int main()
{
    int     n=1;

    // The UDF to be supplied is myUDF
    externalFunction(n, myUDF);

    // The UDF is the classUDF member function of a myClass object
    myClass myClassObj;
    externalFunction(n, myClassObj.classUDF);   // ERROR!!
}
```

I cannot declare the classUDF member function as a static function, so the last line of the code above results in a compilation error!

Comment: Are you sure you typed that right? The delcaration of `externalFunction` looks fictitious.

Comment: @avakar: Should be void `externalFunction(int n, void (*udf)(double*) );` to work.

Comment: @jpalecek: Yeah, that's what I thought, though surprisingly the OP's syntax does actually compile. I wonder why!

Comment: @KerrekSB: The pointer is implicit (sort of like `int arr[]` gets turned into `int* arr`). I actually prefer the OP's method, the more common one contains unnecessary noise.

Comment: down voters, could you please leave a comment! I don't see any reason for down voting!

Answer (score 6):

This is impossible to do - in c++, you must use either a free function, or a static member function, or (in c++11) a lambda without capture to get a function pointer.

GCC allows you to create nested function which could do what you want, but only in C. It uses so-called trampolines to do that (basically small pieces of dynamically generated code). It would be possible to use this feature, but only if you split some of the code calling `externalFunction` to a separate C module.

Another possibility would be generating code at runtime eg. using [libjit](http://www.gnu.org/s/dotgnu/libjit-doc/libjit.html).

So if you're fine with non-reenrant function, create a global/static variable which will point to `this` and use it in your static function.

```
class myClass
{
public:
    static myClass* callback_this;
    static void classUDF(double* a)
    {
        callback_this.realUDF(a);
    };
};
```

Its really horrible code, but I'm afraid you're out of luck with such a bad design as your `externalFunction`.

Comment: How do you usefully find an instance to call `realUDF` on in a captureless lambda?

Comment: @awoodland: You can't. That's why I said it was impossible.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Boost bind or TR1 bind (on recent compilers);;

```
externalFunction(n, boost::bind(&myClass::classUDF, boost::ref(myClassObj)));
```

Unfortunately, I lived in a pipe dream for the last 10 minutes. The only way forward is to call the target using some kind of a static wrapper function. The other answers have various neat (compiler-specific) tidbits on that, but here's the main trick:

```
void externalFunction(int n, void (*udf)(double*) )
{ double x; udf(&x); }

myClass myClassObj;
void wrapper(double* d) { myClassObj.classUDF(d); }

int main()
{
    externalFunction(1, &wrapper);
}
```

### std::function<>

Store a bound function in a variable like this:

```
std::function<void(double*)> stored = std::bind(&myClass::classUDF, boost::ref(myClassObj))
```

(assuming C++0x support in compiler now. I'm sure Boost has a boost::function<> somewhere)

### Vanilla C++ pointers-to-member-function

Without magic like that, you'd need *pointer-to-memberfunction* syntax:

See also live on http://ideone.com/Ld7It

> **Edit** to clarify to the commenters, obviously this only works *iff* you have control over the definition of externalFunction. This is in direct response to the /broken/ snippet int the OP.

```
struct myClass
{
    void classUDF(double* a) { };
};

void externalFunction(int n, void (myClass::*udf)(double*) )
{
    myClass myClassObj;
    double x;
    (myClassObj.*udf)(&x); 
}

int main()
{
    externalFunction(1, &myClass::classUDF);
}
```

### C++98 idiomatic solution

```
// mem_fun_ref example
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main () 
{
    std::vector<std::string> numbers;

    // populate vector:
    numbers.push_back("one");
    numbers.push_back("two");
    numbers.push_back("three");
    numbers.push_back("four");
    numbers.push_back("five");

    std::vector <int> lengths (numbers.size());

    std::transform (numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), lengths.begin(), 
                std::mem_fun_ref(&std::string::length));

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        std::cout << numbers[i] << " has " << lengths[i] << " letters.\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't. Updated the answer. TR1 and C++11 std::function<> solve the function pointer issue, though. Also, C++98 had [`std::mem_fun`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/mem_fun_ref/) all the time, to be used with [`std::bind1`](sthttp://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/bind1st/). Updating answer to show usage

Comment: @GMan: edited my braindamage :( I didn't want to just toss the rest of the answer. It might help someone understand the troubles - by describing the different mechanisms that have been available through the last decade or so.

Comment: @KerrekSB: sorry for my earlier response. I missed the clue. GMan's remark did the trick to wake me up

Comment: @sehe: No problem. This is a common request, and there's never a simple answer :-S

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I do this, when MyClass is a singleton:

```
void externalFunction(int n, void udf(double) );

class MyClass
{
public:
   static MyClass* m_this;
   MyClass(){ m_this = this; }
   static void mycallback(double* x){ m_this->myrealcallback(x); }
   void myrealcallback(double* x);
}

int main()
{
   MyClass myClass;
   externalFunction(0, MyClass::mycallback);
}
```