# How to have a function pointer inside a class?

Tags: c++

"error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘thread::tfun’"

```
Class thread {

  typedef void* (th_fun) (void*);

  th_fun *tfun;

  void create(th_fun *fun=tfun) {

    pthread_create(&t, NULL, fun, NULL);

}

}
```

How to have a function pointer inside a class?

Please note:- static deceleration will make the code compile. But my requirement is to hold the function per object.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079453/c-class-member-function-callback/8079610#8079610

Comment: Not exactly... I need to store/modify it. Use some other time.

Comment: Why not just use `boost::thread`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of pthreads is fine, and you have no pointer-to-member-function here.

The problem is that you're trying to use a non-static member variable as a default parameter for a function, and [you can't do that](http://codepad.org/BXAvJYLA):

```
struct T {
   int x;

   void f(int y = x) {}
};
// Line 2: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'T::x'
// compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

The default argument must be something that's — essentially — a *global*, or at least a name that doesn't require qualification.

Fortunately it's an easy fix!

```
Class thread {

  typedef void* (th_fun) (void*);
  th_fun* tfun;

  void create(th_fun* fun = NULL) {      // perfectly valid default parameter
     if (fun == NULL) {
        fun = tfun;                      // works now because there's an object
     }                                   // context whilst we're inside `create`

     pthread_create(&t, NULL, fun, NULL);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it using a non-static member function `t`.

What you can do is passed the pointer of the `class thread` to `t` through the `void *` parameter. Or if you still have other parameters for `t`, you can wrap them all (including the point to `class thread`) in a structure and pass the pointer of an instance of the structure.

As mentioned by others, only an `extern "C"` function would fit the need of `pthread_create`.

Comment: You cannot pass a static member function to `pthread_create`; if your compiler conforms to the C++ standard, it won't compile.  The function you pass must be `extern "C"`, and member functions, even static, can't be.

Comment: Oh, that will be a problem. I'm not quite familiar with `pthread_create`.