# Saving function pointer in a class

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I pass a class member function as a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400257/how-can-i-pass-a-class-member-function-as-a-callback)

I have two classes A and B

```
class A
{
public:
   void SetHandler(void (*p)(OMX_BUFFERHEADERTYPE*)){ Handler = p; };
private:
  void (*Handler)(OMX_BUFFERHEADERTYPE*);
}
```

and

in B I have a function

```
void B::handler(OMX_BUFFERHEADERTYPE* p){};
```

now when (from B) I call

```
inst_a.SetHandler(&B::handler);
```

i get the following error:

```
B.cpp:740:69: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::SetHandler(void (COMXVideo::*)(OMX_BUFFERHEADERTYPE*))’
B.cpp:740:69: note: candidate is:
A.h:161:8: note: void A::SetHandler(void (*)(OMX_BUFFERHEADERTYPE*))
A.h:161:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘void (B::*)(OMX_BUFFERHEADERTYPE*)’ to ‘void (*)(OMX_BUFFERHEADERTYPE*)’
```

what am I doing wrong?

Best Regards

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types.html

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/memfnptr-vs-fnptr.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass a class member function as a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400257/how-can-i-pass-a-class-member-function-as-a-callback), [Using a C++ class member function as a C callback function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000663/using-a-c-class-member-function-as-a-c-callback-function), [C++ class member function callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079453/c-class-member-function-callback)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&B::handler` is not a function pointer, but a [pointer to member function](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html). If `B::handler` doesn't need members of `B`, you can define it `static`. Then `SetHandler(&B::handler)` will work.

If you must have a pointer to member function, you can define it as

```
void (B::*Handler)(OMX_BUFFERHEADERTYPE*);
```

when you call such a member function, you need a pointer to an object as well

```
(inst_b->*Handler)(omxbuffer);
```

or with a reference

```
(inst_b.*Handler)(omxbuffer);
```

Comment: but it does need them :(

Comment: so there is no way not to reference B in the definition of the Handler? I wanted a *general* function pointer reference... Like in C

Comment: @Stasik You can do that, but pointer to function (as in C) and pointer to member function (as in &B::handler) are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

try somthing like this:

```
template<typename C>
class EventObject
{

    public:
        typedef void (C::*FunctionType)();

        template <typename ... T>
        EventObject(C& obj,FunctionType methode): obj (obj), callback (methode) {};

       void execute(){obj.*callback();};

    private:
        C& obj;
        FunctionType callback;
};
```