# Error while creating thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

Im doing a send sms program, but when im creating a connection with server in a thread im getting an error.

```
g++ -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -o main Socket.cpp ServerSocket.cpp modemSMS_w.cpp main.cpp Config.cpp -lpthread -lserial -lxml2 -lmysqlclient
modemSMS_w.cpp: In member function ‘void modem::enviasms()’:
modemSMS_w.cpp:96:77: error: cannot convert ‘void* (modem::*)(void*)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’
```

The program:

```
#include "modemSMS_w.hpp"
#define CTRL_C "\x1A"

using namespace LibSerial;
using namespace std;

modem::modem()
{
}

void *modem::func_servidor(void *ptr)
{

ServerSocket server(30001);

        try {
                ServerSocket new_sock;
                while(1)
                {
                        server.accept(new_sock);
                        cout << "Conexao aceita" << endl;
                }
        }
        catch (SocketException& e) {
                cout << "Erro: Criando Servidor" << endl;
        }

}

int modem::setSerial() {
.....
....
...
}

void modem::enviasms(){

  pthread_t thread_servidor;
  pthread_cond_t cv;

  const int PORT_MON = 30000;
  string serialPort = "/dev/ttyS0";

  int argc;
  int ret;
  char **argv;

    cout << "\n------------------------\n  MODEM GPRS \n------------------------" << endl;
    string mensagem ="Conversao";
    mensagem.c_str();

    ret = pthread_cond_init(&cv, NULL);
    bool envia = true;
    envia = true;
    if (ret != 0)
    {
            cout << "Erro na criação do evento. Por favor reeinicie o programa." << endl;
    }

    //ERROR IN THIS LINE
    pthread_create(&thread_servidor, NULL,&modem::func_servidor, (void* ) true );

    Config config;
    SerialStream ssStream;
    setSerial();

....
...
}
```

Sorry, in dont know almost nothing creating thread in C++.Already tried to solve this out, but with no sucess.

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to use the pthread_create primitive for such a basic usage but if you are using a modern C++ compiler, you better off using `std::thread` (or `boost:thread`). Also, for your problem, you are passing a pointer to a member function where a pointer to a free function is expected. Those are not the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a "simple" function pointer from a member function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958553/how-to-get-a-simple-function-pointer-from-a-member-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a static function to your class and use it in pthread_create function:

```
class modem {
    public:
        //...
        static void* thread_func(void* arg);
        //...
};

void* modem::thread_func(void* arg) {
    return reinterpret_cast<modem*>(arg)->func_servidor();
}

void *modem::func_servidor() {
    // some code
}

void modem::enviasms(){
    //some code scipped
    if(pthread_create(&thread_servidor, NULL, &modem::thread_func, reinterpret_cast<void*>(this)) != 0) {
        //some error handling code
    }
    //...
    if(pthread_join(thread_servidor, NULL) != 0) {
    // handle error
    }
}
```

But, IMHO, it's much better to use boost or std threads. You do not need static function with this approach:

```
auto thr = std::thread{ &modem::func_servidor, this };
//...
thr.join();
```

Notice, however, that you must check that object that `this` points to will exist while you thread exists.

Comment: @Neto Be careful - `this` pointer must be valid while thread exists. If the modem object is destroyed and thread still exists, you will get undefined behavior.

Comment: It worked fine...I had to do some changes, but u helped me a lot man...thx!

Answer (score 1):

You never create an instance of your `Modem` class, so how can a member function of that class be called?

Member functions need a member to operate on. Don't pass a pointer to a member function to `pthread_create`. Create a non-member function that calls the member function and pass a pointer to that to `pthread_create`.

Comment: Im moving from C to C++, so i dont know almost nothing about class...How can i create this non-member function and pass a pointer to that pthread_create?

Comment: @Neto I would strongly urge you to forget about threads until you understand the basics of C++. You'll never sort these issues out when you're trying to do all of them at once. If "you can't call a non-static class member function without a class member" isn't obvious to you, or you don't know what a "this" pointer is, you have no business messing with threads and classes at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, I'm already studying, but I'm not having much patience..sorry for my ignorance